# Replace 'space' in certain value of csv columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got the next csv file:

```
Summary,Issue key,Issue id,Issue Type,Status,Project key,Attachment,Attachment.1,Attachment.2,Attachment.3,Attachment.4,Attachment.5

Find issue,IS-11,576,Task,Solved,One-1,10/28/21 11:49;Olga_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4
```

I need to choose all the attachments values and replace the "space" in the filename to "%20".
The main problem **is to skip the first 'space' after the date** in the attachment value and also to get all the attachment value.
I tried to use standart csv reader, pandas and etc. but I can only get name of the column

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("SALUPRJBKK_new_10.csv")
for i in data:
    if "Attachment" in i:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select 'Attachment' columns using `filter` and `replace` all whitespaces by '%20' then `update` your dataframe in place:

```
df.update(df.filter(like='Attachment').replace(' ', '%20', regex=True))
```

My advise if you need to escape HTML entities is to use `quote` from `urllib` module:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

df.update(df.filter(like='Attachment').fillna('').applymap(quote))
```

**Update**

Try:

```
out = df.filter(like='Attachment').unstack().str.split(';').explode()
out = out.where(~(out.str.startswith('file://').fillna(False)), 
                out.str.replace(' ', '%20'))
df.update(out.dropna().groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(';'.join).unstack(0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But how to skip the first space of the attachment value which is after the date? I need to let them.

Comment: For your current string `'10/28/21 11:49;Olga_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4'` what is the expected outcome, please?

Comment: my bad
I have this value:
"10/28/21 11:49;Lyubov_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4"
Outcome should be:
"10/28/21 11:49;Lyubov_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28%2014-38-01-372.mp4"

there is a first space it should be left
and another space in the filename should be replaced

Comment: there could be several spaces

Comment: '10/28/21 11:49;Olga_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28%2014-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28%2014-38-01-372.mp4' -- outcome

Comment: maybe we could add something to replace spaces in string after several characters?

Comment: I need to know if all rows have the same format and (important) all `Attachment` columns.

Comment: I mean in your sample, only the first `Attachment` column has a value. Others are set to NaN. In other rows, you have probably some values in other `Attachment` columns so do you need to skip unconditionally the first space (in all columns of each row)?

Comment: @Skazalasobaka. Is it possible to say after the first `;` replace all space by %20?

Comment: Some of attachment columns have NO values
but if they have, the all have simillar format
and I need to skip all first spaces
maybe it should be enough to start replacing after file://

Answer (score 0):

consider specifying the separotor:

```
data = pd.read_csv("SALUPRJBKK_new_10.csv", sep=",")
```

Note: there is a mix of seperator in your example "," or ";"

and if you want to acces only to "Attachment" do:

```
data["Attachment"]
```

Comment: I have thousands of values(
I need to do this in the Attachment.1,Attachment.2,Attachment.3 and etc.
So in each attachment column I should find incorrect filename and correct it.

Comment: `for c in ["Attachment.1", "Attachment2", ...]:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda elem: elem.replace(" ", "%20")`

Comment: Thank you!
Could you please advise how to skip the firs space after the date, it's between date and time and I need to left it and replace only in the filename.
Attachment key has a big value:
 10/28/21 11:49;Olga_Sokolova;SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4;file://SALUPRJBKK/SALUPRJBKK-1663/SALUPRJBKK-1663_2021-10-28 14-38-01-372.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I think do you need a url encode.

Try with this:

```
import urllib.parse

query = 'Hellóóó W r l d @ Pyt@@ h on.mp4'
newUrl = urllib.parse.quote(query)
print(newUrl)
```

And now the encode result:

```
Hell%C3%B3%C3%B3%C3%B3%20W%20r%20l%20d%20%40%20Pyt%40%40%20h%20on.mp4
```

The text or url is encoded and change all the special characters in string.